# Writing length and mirror in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need 2 programs that create below example outputs:

1)

```
   ?-length_full([a,[b,c],[d]],R).

   R=4
```

2)

```
   ?-mirror([a,[b,c],[d,e]],R).

   R=[[e,d],[c,b],a]
```

I tried but couldn't write the programs...so please help me!

Comment: Please post your attempts, and we'll help you fix them.  Also, if this is homework, it would be appropriate to say so.  Thanks!

Comment: Explain in natural language what your program is supposed to do. This is always the first step in programming. If you want a program that prints out "4" then this is easy to achieve (length_full(_, 4)), but I think you want something else. What?

Comment: What do you expect as answer for ?- length_full([X], N).

Comment: in the program no.1, length_full must return the length of list. for example, if list is [a,[b,c],[d]] then its argument 'R' must set to '4' return 'R=4'.

Comment: in program No.2, mirror must reverse the list. for example, if list is [a,[b,c],[d,e]] then argument R must set to reverse list of [a,[b,c],[d,e]] (i.e. [[e,d],[c,b],a]) and R=[[e,d],[c,b],a] must returned.

Comment: please move your comments into the description of the question, where they belong.